# Does plotly-python support to "add_traces" behind the main figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Does plotly-python support to "add_traces" behind the main figure?

E. g. I create a figure with plotly express and add traces. If the traces, like in the following example, overlap with the main figure, the traces are plotted above the main figure and covering it. 
Is it possible to plot the traces behind the main figure?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

sample = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,10,10),-np.linspace(0,10,10))),
        'y': np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,10,10),-np.linspace(0,10,10))),
        'iteration': np.tile(np.arange(10),2),
        'class': np.repeat(np.arange(2),10)    
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(sample, x="x", y="y", animation_frame="iteration", animation_group="class", 
            color='class', color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Rainbow)


grouped_traces = [ 
    go.Scatter(x=group['x'],y=group['y'],mode='lines', opacity=0.8,
            showlegend=False, line=dict(color='grey', width=4, dash='dot'))
    for _, group in sample.groupby('class')
]

fig.add_traces(grouped_traces)


fig.show()
```

Comment: Your specific figure is a bit complicated because of the animation. Are you interested in general answer to this, or the particular figure produced by your code sample?

Comment: I see. My question is definitely related to an animation. Therefore I created a random animation to illustrate this. Maybe my example could be simplified without animation and then the answer could be generalized to animations as well.